# YamlDotNet generate comments during POCO serialization

Tags: yamldotnet

Is there any way to generate comments during serialization? I serialize some objects that I would like to decorate with comments.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer does not support emitting comments. This is so because [comments are a presentation detail and are not associated with a particular node](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2767100). If you really want comments, you can create a YamlDocument, which allows you to add comments to it.